# error- IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, error-handling

I am a beginner with the Python. I am trying to run the following code to replace some labels in .txt annotation files.

```
import os

for txt_in in os.listdir(r"uncorrected-YOLO_darknet"):
    with open(txt_in) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            word=line.split(" ")[0]
            if word="6":
                word.replace('6', '5')
            elif word="9":
                word.replace('9', '6')
            elif word="10":
                word.replace('10', '7')
            elif word="11":
                word.replace('11', '8')
            else:
                continue
            break
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
File "<tokenize>", line 7
    if word="6":
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I tried to find the indentation error but it looked alright to me. Plz help. tnx!

Comment: You've got mixed tabs and spaces. Find your editor's "convert tabs to spaces" button and hit it, set your indentation to spaces, and check for this if it comes up again.

Comment: tnx @ user2357112 supports Monica. it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if/elif` takes a statement that returns a `boolean` value.

`==` is one such operator that checks for equality and returns `true/false`.

What you have in your code is `=`, which is an assignment operator and it does not check for equality.

Replace all the `if/elif` statements like this:

```
if word == "6":
```

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong Syntex of If and elif condition
 
Try below code

```
        if word=="6":
            word.replace('6', '5')
        elif word=="9":
            word.replace('9', '6')
        elif word=="10":
            word.replace('10', '7')
        elif word=="11":
            word.replace('11', '8')
        else:
            continue
        break
```